# Is there a way to reduce performance once a temperature threshold is reached

Tags: overheating, temperature

My laptop (Toshiba Satellite L655 - 1e8) overheats (and shuts down). Often. I was wondering if there is a way to reduce performance once the temperature reaches a certain threshold.

Thanks!

P.S. I'm not doing anything very resource-intensive... It sometimes overheats while just watching a flash video on chromium. Anything more and its practically guaranteed to happen after a while. I did clean the fan, but perhaps not well enough.

Answer (score 0):

The hardware is supposed to do this if it absolutely must, and is really not supposed to overheat in the first place.  If it does then it is defective and you should complain to the manufacturer and return it for a refund if you still can.

Comment: Its not new, so I can't do that... I just want to use the one I have without worrying about it shutting down unexpectedly

Comment: @NBcode, you might try manually lowering your cpu frequency: http://askubuntu.com/a/37997/8500

Comment: On SUSE I could adjust something in /proc to slow down the clock. But on ubuntu, I can't find it. Sooo, I know this can be done! I have the same problem. (thats why I am here...)

Comment: @jim, see my previous comment...